# Reading Avro file in Spark and extracting column values

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I want to read an avro file using Spark (I am using Spark 1.3.0 so I don't have data frames)

I read the avro file using this piece of code

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

private def readAvro(sparkContext: SparkContext, path: String) = {
  sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile[
    AvroKey[GenericRecord],
    NullWritable,
    AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]
  ](path)
}
```

I execute this and get an RDD. Now from RDD, how do I extract value of specific columns? like loop through all records and give value of column name?

[edit]As suggested by Justin below I tried

```
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[AvroKey[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]](input)
rdd.map(record=> record._1.get("accountId")).toArray().foreach(println)
```

but I get an error

```
<console>:34: error: value get is not a member of org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey[org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord]
              rdd.map(record=> record._1.get("accountId")).toArray().foreach(println)
```

Comment: Spark 1.3.0 _does_ have DataFrames: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: and is there a way to load an avro file in a spark 1.3.0 dataframe? I don't see anything in the documentation link which you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AvroKey` has a `datum` method to extract the wrapped value. And `GenericRecord` has a `get` method that accepts the column name as a string. So you can just extract the columns using a `map`

```
rdd.map(record=>record._1.datum.get("COLNAME"))
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and updated my question above. I am getting an error about the `get` function. I am using Spark 1.3.0 on Cloudera Platform.